# How to return a file along with a error message to view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net-mvc and right now I'm working on returning a excel file along with an error message if the returning file has column missing, when the user clicked the button. I use `return File()`to return my file to view, but I don't know how to send the error message together. (I'd tried ViewBag but it didn't work) How to send a file back to view along with an error message?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to use Ajax for generate the excel file to a temp folder in server, and download it by the ajax response, the fronend code will like below:

```
$.blockUI({ message: '<h3><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/busy.gif")" /> Please wait a moment...</h3>' });    
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ExportExcel","YourController")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function (data) {
        //console.log(data.result);
        $.unblockUI();
        if (data.fileName != "") {
            window.location.href = "@Url.RouteUrl(new { Controller = "YourController", Action = "Download"})/?file=" + data.fileName;
        }
    });
```

in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ExportExcel()
{
    DataTable dt = DataService.GetData();
    var fileName = "Excel_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".xls";
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/temp"), fileName);

    using (var exportData = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Utility.WriteDataTableToExcel(dt, ".xls", exportData);

        FileStream file = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        exportData.WriteTo(file);
        file.Close();
    }

    var errorMessage = "you can return the errors in here!";

    return Json(new { fileName = fileName, errorMessage = "" });
}
```

and the download action

```
[HttpGet]
[DeleteFileAttribute]
public virtual ActionResult Download(string file)
{
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/temp"), file);
    return File(fullPath, "application/vnd.ms-excel", file);
}
```

in here, I created a delete filter for auto delete the file after download:

```
/// <summary>
/// The Action filter for delete the file after downloaded
/// </summary>
public class DeleteFileAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
        string filePath = (filterContext.Result as FilePathResult).FileName;
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend returning the file as the model and adding any errors to the `ModelState` in your controller like this:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Key", "Error Message");
```

If you would like to parse the `ModelState` into JSON to use in javascript you can use this method:

```
public static string ParseModelState(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{
    if (modelState == null) return "";
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    for (var i = 0; i < modelState.Keys.Count; i++)
    {
        var firstOrDefault = modelState.Values.ElementAt(i).Errors.FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstOrDefault != null)
            dic.Add(modelState.Keys.ElementAt(i), firstOrDefault.ErrorMessage);
    }
    return System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(dic);
}
```

And in your View:

```
var modelState = @Html.Raw(Helpers.ParseModelState(ViewData.ModelState));
```

Answer (score 0):

is your file store on the server? if yes, you can return the URL to the file as par of a JSON and in the JavaScript you can display error and the load the file in a new window

```
return return Json(new {error="Error Message", fileurl="http://yoursite.com/file.etx"});
```

on client side ( i am guessing you are posting information)

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Control")',
        data: { para: "value" },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) { 
          $('#errorlabel').html(data.error);
          window.open(data.fileurl,_blank);
    },
        error: errorFunc
    });
```

hope this gives you a good idea to start