# Download a file using ajax from ASP.Net Webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I need to download a file that is created on the server as a binary array, as follows:

Server code is handler page (ashx):

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var cId = context.Request.QueryString["CanID"];

        if (int.Parse(cId ) > 0)
        {
            var sc = ControllerAccess.Instance();
            var cv = sc.GetUser(int.Parse(cId), SessionHandler.LoggedOnUser);
            if (cv.Bytes != null && cv.Bytes.Length > 0)
            {
                var dTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");

                var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                response.ClearContent();
                response.Clear();
                response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dTime + "-" + Id + "-" + "CandidateRecord" + cv.FileExtension);
                response.BinaryWrite(cv.Bytes);
                response.Flush();
                response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

How Can I get that file on the client using ajax? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can't just download the file by ajax directly, you should need to save the file to a temp folder in server and return the file name for download after ajax call, please see my answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40606952/382576)